# Почему срабатывание по таймеру происходит только один раз?

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

Задача - обновлять DataGridview данными из объекта json каждые n секунд

Вот классы для форматирования данных

```
 public class Akks
        {
            [JsonProperty("addlogin")]
            [DisplayName("Логин")]
            public string addlogin { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("addmlogin")]
            [DisplayName("Почта")]
            public string addmlogin { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("addpass")]
            [DisplayName("Пароль")]
            public string addpass { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("Follow")]
            [DisplayName("Подписки")]
            public string Follow { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("status")]
            [DisplayName("Статус")]
            public string status { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("addmpass")]
            [DisplayName("Пароль почты")]
            public string addmpass { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("NOFollow")]
            [DisplayName("Ошибка")]
            public string NOFollow { get; set; }
        }


        public class LibAkks
        {
            [JsonProperty("akks")]
            public IList<Akks> akks { get; set; }
        }
```

Вот код обновления:

```
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            string json = "{\"akks\":[{\"addlogin\":\"" + Help.addlogin + "\",\"addmlogin\":\"" + Help.addmlogin + "\",\"addpass\":\"" + Help.addpass + "\",\"Follow\":\"0\",\"status\":\"Добавлен:готов к запуску!\",\"addmpass\":\""+Help.addmpass + "\",\"NOFollow\":\"\"}]}";
            string item = "{\"addlogin\":\"" + Help.addlogin + "\",\"addmlogin\":\"" + Help.addmlogin + "\",\"addpass\":\"" + Help.addpass + "\",\"Follow\":\"0\",\"status\":\"Добавлен:готов к запуску!\",\"addmpass\":\"" + Help.addmpass + "\",\"NOFollow\":\"\"}";

            if (jo == null)
            {
                jo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LibAkks>(json);
            }
            else
            {
                jo.akks.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Akks>(item));
            }

            dataGridView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = jo.akks));
```

Устанавливаю таймер на обновление, но оно почему то проходит только 1 раз и дальше не обновляет таблицу хотя таймер работает и массив пополняется

json проверял в консоли, но DataSource работает только один раз, - не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: `...DataSource = null; ...DataSource = jo.akks;`

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: "Коллекцию строк нельзя очистить программно, если элемент управления DataGridView привязан к данным объекта, отличного от IBindingList, который поддерживает уведомление об изменении и допускает удаление."